# Updating `{{ forms.dateField }}` value from GET variable

Tags: plugin-development, localization, datetime

I want to use the built-in Craft field macros to show a date field in a plugin template for filtering.

I can retrieve the submitted value on any submission (via GET) but how do I then prepopulate said date field with the previously submitted value? 
When I try to simply pass the submission into the value property I get an `Array to string conversion` error.

My plugin template code …

```
{% set start = craft.request.getParam('start') %}    
{{ dump(start) }}
{{ forms.dateField({
    label: 'Start date',
    id: 'start',
    name: 'start',
    value: start }) }}
```

So my question is; is there anyway I can pass a value into the dateField that has been submitted via a POST or GET variable?

Comment: It might be helpful to show us your `start` variable

Comment: What does `{{ dump(start) }}` output?

Comment: @RobinSchambach if I pass the value posted from the dateField element then I get  'date' => string '08/11/2017' (length=10) (where the above code example generates an input field with a name of `start[date]`).

Comment: @BradBell this outputs:

    `array (size=1)`
    `'date' => string '08/11/2017' (length=10)`

Comment: If i try to pass my date string as a value into {{ forms.dateField }} I get following error:

`Impossible to invoke a method ("localeDate") on a string variable ("11-08-2017")`

Comment: Thanks both - had overseen suggestion on Slack for following which works:

`value: now|date_modify(start.date)`

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps spoke to soon. 

Bizarrely when using the datefield it outputs dates in the following format DD-MM-YYYY. However, when I capture this value and try to output it in my template it is assuming that the DD is MM and MM is DD.

So for example, with a value of 12 November it posts `11-12-2017` as the GET value but in my template it is assuming this is 11 December.

Any further thoughts? Obviously some kind of mix-up with localisation but seems strange that the datefield is outputting in one kind and then the template is interpreting this value in a different way.

Thoughts?